# The Lagrangian of a Rocket

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, rocket-science

I am trying to understand how to write the Lagrangian of a system which consists of a rocket losing gas mass in a rate of $\frac{dm}{dt}$, the gas moving in a velocity of $u_0$ in the rocket's view? Gravity can be neglected.

I wrote it as the kinetic energy of the gas, in the rocket's system. But I guess it isn't complete. What is the potential energy in this problem?

In [this](http://scienceblogs.com/builtonfacts/2009/07/22/this-week-the-science-blogosph/) blog he seems to try and take care of this problem, but the equations there seem to have nothing to do with the subject...

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): In the [ideal rocket problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) (where we assume the rocket is a point particle with no moment of inertia), the dynamical variable is the position ${\bf r}(t)$. On the other hand, the mass rate $u=\dot{m}<0$ (and the orientation of the rocket) are control/external parameters.

Comment: (cont.) Therefore the appropriate variational framework (especially if we are interested in time-dependent questions) is [optimal control theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_control) rather than just the bare Lagrangian formalism for ${\bf r}(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the Lagrangian (in Cartesian coordinates) for an object of mass $m$ in a potential $V$ would be
$$L=T-V\to\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2+\dot{z}^2)-V(x,y,z)\tag{1}$$
It then follows that for a coordinates $q$,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{q}}\right)=\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}\to\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(m\dot{q}\right)=-\frac{\partial V}{\partial q}\to \ddot{q}=-\frac{1}{m}\frac{\partial V}{\partial q}\tag{2}$$
For a free particle, $V=0$ and $\frac{\partial V}{\partial q}=0$, and so $\ddot{q}=0$.

However, we have to account for the fact that the propulsion comes from a force that is *not* derived from an external potential. Just like friction, we have to treat this separately by adding an additional term to the right-hand side:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{q}}\right)=-\frac{\partial V}{\partial q}-F_q$$
These are called the Euler-Lagrange equations of the first kind.

Comment: Wouldn't your equation imply (ignoring potential) $m(t)\ddot{q}=-\dot{q} \dot{m}(t)$, as opposed to the correct equation $m(t)\ddot{q}=-u_0\dot{m}(t)$?

Comment: Yeah, as stated in the OP

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy Never mind; I re-read the question. Okay, I'm trying to figure out where I went wrong.

Comment: Newton's Laws are not valid if $dm/dt \neq 0$.  Does this analysis work in that case?  Does it produce the rocket equation?

Comment: I see you edited the post to eliminate $\dot{m}$.   I'd like to see the rocket equation derived from a Lagrangian.  Google hasn't helped me with that.  Can you find a reference, or if it's short enough, provide the derivation?

Comment: @garyp I haven't been able to find a good source, either, even after a lot of searching.

Comment: @garyp There is the following paper (sorry about the paywall) https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/3.1626?journalCode=aiaaj